# How to make views hidden by keyboard scrollable

Tags: android, xml

There is a screen. When the keyboard is shown, some of element are hidden (screenshots below).

[image]

I am trying to implement scrolling when some of elements are hidden - I want to make bottom button (blue) constrained to the bottom part of screen or keyboard and to make hidden part (orange) scrollable. Something like that:

[image]

Here is my layout xml that doesn't work - no scrolling when elements are hidden:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


              <Here are views. Some of them are constrained to the top of parent ConstraintLayout, some to the bottom. >



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Seems like I've missed something, but I have no idea what exactly. How can I fix it and implement

Comment: if you talking about the elements position when keyboard is showed/hidden, you have to manage the attribute windowSoftInputMode in manifest for your activity.
read this link for help: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-Soft-Keyboard

Comment: I am talking about scrollability of elements when keyboard is shown. Keyboard is shown, some of elements of the screen are hidden by it and I'd like to make it scrollable

Comment: I am not sure about all the other components in your xml. Maybe you require a nested scroll view?